# convert RTMP streaming to HLS Streaming using FFMPEG

Tags: video, ffmpeg, streaming, rtmp

i am doing rtmp streaming to HLS streaming using FFMPEG , the following code is used to convert my desired option

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -i rtmp://xxxx.com:1935/live/live1 -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 400k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 http://xxxxx.com/live.m3u8
```

after running this command it's return following error

```
Unrecognized option 'hls_time'
Failed to set value '10' for option 'hls_time'
```

How to clear this error

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

`ffmpeg -v verbose -i rtmp://host:port/stream -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf
18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 400k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -flags -global_header -hls_time
10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 pathToFolderYouWantTo/streamName.m3u8`

Answer (score 0):

if you're looking for a professional software there is a software solution to your problem, its a freeware program with a paid web interface. its called Nimble streamer. the transcoding option is also paid, but it can do it all automatically, you simply setup the web interface on the server to output an hls stream and just stream to the server using rtmp, then just playback the server address through your preferred playback setup....
https://wmspanel.com/transcoder

good luck!

Sources: I tested the trial version